# Bad query plan on subquery with union all and a where clause

Tags: postgresql

The following query produces non optimal query plan.

```sql
WITH
  targets as (
    select 'bike' vehicle, id, dealer_name FROM bikes WHERE frame_size = 52
    union all
    select 'car' vehicle, id, dealer_name FROM cars
    -- In the real use case I have here dozens of tables
  )
SELECT
  dealers.name dealer,
  targets.vehicle,
  targets.id
FROM
  dealers
  JOIN targets
    ON dealers.name = targets.dealer_name
  WHERE dealers.id in (54,12,456,315,468)
```

The join condition is not "pushed" down to `bikes` and `cars` tables and the query plan contains Sequential Scans on both tables even though both have an index on `dealer_name` column.

```
Hash Join  (cost=21.53..4528.63 rows=545 width=41) (actual time=0.349..46.148 rows=551 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (bikes.dealer_name = dealers.name)
  Buffers: shared hit=1095
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..3959.24 rows=108483 width=41) (actual time=0.012..33.637 rows=108321 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=1082
        ->  Seq Scan on bikes  (cost=0.00..1791.00 rows=8483 width=41) (actual time=0.011..9.304 rows=8321 loops=1)
              Filter: (frame_size = 52)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 91679
              Buffers: shared hit=541
        ->  Seq Scan on cars  (cost=0.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=41) (actual time=0.012..15.126 rows=100000 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=541
  ->  Hash  (cost=21.46..21.46 rows=5 width=5) (actual time=0.024..0.026 rows=5 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        Buffers: shared hit=13
        ->  Index Scan using dealers_pkey on dealers  (cost=0.28..21.46 rows=5 width=5) (actual time=0.011..0.021 rows=5 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{54,12,456,315,468}'::integer[]))
              Buffers: shared hit=13
Planning Time: 0.195 ms
Execution Time: 46.252 ms
```

If the `WHERE` clause is removed from the `bikes` subquery the query plan is much better.

```
Nested Loop  (cost=5.34..2120.38 rows=1004 width=41) (actual time=0.042..1.460 rows=997 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=943
  ->  Index Scan using dealers_pkey on dealers  (cost=0.28..21.46 rows=5 width=5) (actual time=0.015..0.030 rows=5 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{54,12,456,315,468}'::integer[]))
        Buffers: shared hit=13
  ->  Append  (cost=5.07..417.78 rows=200 width=41) (actual time=0.023..0.260 rows=199 loops=5)
        Buffers: shared hit=930
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on bikes  (cost=5.07..208.39 rows=100 width=41) (actual time=0.021..0.119 rows=97 loops=5)
              Recheck Cond: (dealer_name = dealers.name)
              Heap Blocks: exact=450
              Buffers: shared hit=460
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bikes_dealer_name_idx  (cost=0.00..5.04 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=97 loops=5)
                    Index Cond: (dealer_name = dealers.name)
                    Buffers: shared hit=10
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on cars  (cost=5.07..208.39 rows=100 width=41) (actual time=0.019..0.121 rows=102 loops=5)
              Recheck Cond: (dealer_name = dealers.name)
              Heap Blocks: exact=460
              Buffers: shared hit=470
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cars_dealer_name_idx  (cost=0.00..5.04 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=102 loops=5)
                    Index Cond: (dealer_name = dealers.name)
                    Buffers: shared hit=10
Planning Time: 0.236 ms
Execution Time: 1.533 ms
```

Can I somehow force to push the join condition to sub queries and force the index usage? Or are there some nice ways to make the query to perform better?

This is just a simple example and in my real use case there are dozens of tables in the `targets` CTE query. I would not like to rewrite the query to include separate joins for each target table.

Sample schema and test can be generated with:

```sql
-- Available also at: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cEXt8HXSaQzsQ2yBDA2Z4H/7

CREATE TABLE dealers AS
SELECT
  id,
  (SELECT string_agg(CHR(65+(random() * 25)::integer), '') FROM generate_series(1, 4) WHERE id>0) name
FROM generate_series(1, 1000) AS id
;
ALTER TABLE dealers ADD primary key (id);
CREATE INDEX ON dealers(name);


CREATE TABLE bikes AS
SELECT
  generate_series AS id,
  (SELECT name FROM dealers WHERE dealers.id = (SELECT (random()*1000)::int WHERE generate_series>0)) AS dealer_name,
  (random()*12+50)::int as frame_size
FROM generate_series(1, 100000);
ALTER TABLE bikes ADD primary key (id);
CREATE INDEX ON bikes(dealer_name);


CREATE TABLE cars AS
SELECT
  generate_series as id,
  (SELECT name FROM dealers WHERE dealers.id = (SELECT (random()*1000)::int WHERE generate_series>0)) AS dealer_name,
  (random()*7+14)::int as wheel_size
FROM generate_series(1, 100000);
ALTER TABLE cars ADD primary key (id);
CREATE INDEX ON cars(dealer_name);


ANALYZE;
```

Comment: I looked at this again, and the problem is the `WHERE frame_size = 52`. Without that, you get the plan you would like. I guess your only option is to explicitly push the join into all `UNION ALL` members.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Thanks for getting back to this! That was also my conclusion. I managed to get a magnitude improvement on cases where number of dealers interested is small using SELECT * FROM dealers CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ... WHERE name=dealer_name UNION ALL SELECT ... WHERE name=dealer_name ) WHERE dealer.id IN (1,2,3);
But this is much slower than the original query when number of dealers queried grows.